# Android proguard enable code through exception method not found exception

Tags: android, android-proguard

below code i used to get application size. and works fine when i export the apk without enabling the pro-guard,but when i enable the pro-guard for export apk it through exception method not found.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

  Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
"getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.android.mms",
new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
        throws RemoteException {

        Log.i(TAG, "codeSize: " + pStats.codeSize);
    }
})
```

Any help to overcome this problem.

Comment: why this is a problem only with proguard.

Answer (score 0):

while using `Proguard`. I faced same issue. it occurs because of Reflection.

just add this line to proguard and fixed this issue

```
-keep class android.content.pm.* { *; }
```